# Two lilypond commands in LaTeX

Tags: undefined, lilypond

With previous version of LaTeX (Slackware-14.2 + lilypond-2.18.2) I could add many lilypondfiles in one line. With lilypond-2.22.1 and texlive-2021.21048 is not working. I suspect lilypond-book is the problem.

Non-working lytex example:

```
Note c \lilypond[fragment,notime]{c'}, note d \lilypond[fragment,notime]{d'}
```

Error is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.302 }, note d \lilypond
                         [fragment,notime]{d'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to break the lilypond files / or inline text like this

```
Note c \lilypond[fragment,notime]{c'},
note d \lilypond[fragment,notime]{d'}
```

Same goes with tables. lytex example:

```
Not working. Without break. Was working with previous versions of LaTex / lilypond
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
   \lilypond[fragment,relative=2,staffsize=26]{c} & Not working: \lilypond[fragment,relative=2,staffsize=26]{d}  \\
\end{tabular}

Working - with break
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
   \lilypond[fragment,relative=2,staffsize=26]{c} &
   \lilypond[fragment,relative=2,staffsize=26]{d}  \\ % break to work.
\end{tabular}
```